# How to view the user limits like max_queries or max_updates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, users

How to show that I've imposed limitations for queries per hour ?

Can't find anything online or notes. Would appreciate anybody's help on this.

Comment: What is your MySQL version please ?

Comment: hi, its 8.0.16. thanks

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Setting Account Resource Limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-resources.html) (valid for 5.5+ at least).

> The server stores resource limits for an account in the `user` table row corresponding to the account. The max_questions, max_updates, and max_connections columns store the per-hour limits, and the max_user_connections column stores the MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS limit.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('\'', user, '\'', '@', '\'', host, '\'') account,
       max_questions,
       max_updates,
       max_connections,
       max_user_connections
FROM mysql.user;
```

Comment: hi, sorry but i'm new to programming. do i copy this verbatim or